# Automatically Update Criteria in AVERAGEIFS Function - Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, average

I'm not sure if this is even possible, but I figure it's worth asking.

[image]

In the screenshot above, you can see the formula I have.  It's working just fine.  You'll notice that there are a lot of different criterion in that formula; they are month, day, and time slot (plus an extra one that doesn't really play into this question here).

What I'm wondering is this: is it possible to do this formula for one row and then copy it paste it so that the "day" criteria (which is where it says 'Flare 2Data'!$B$6:$B$262024, "=1") automatically iterates as you drag it down?  What I'm having to do now is copy and paste this equation in each cell and manually click on all of them and type in the day.  And then I have to do that for every month of the year.  Is there a better way?

Comment: Why would this get downvoted?  I've already looked into it and can't find the answer to the question.  I'm sure someone has wondered this same question before.  I really wish people wouldn't be so negative on this site sometimes.

Comment: What do you mean you want it to iterate? can you post perhaps three examples of how the formula changes? I'm thinking you could probably use `Indirect()` somehow...

Comment: So for example, look at cell B5.  You'll see that criteria shows that the month is equal to 4, the day is equal to 1, and the time slot is equal to 1.  In cell B6, the day should be equal to 2.  Cell B7, the day is equal to 3 and so on.  Also, as you go from left to right, the time slot criteria should increase by one each time.  Right now I am doing this manually by clicking on the formula each time and changing the criteria.  There has to be a better way.

Comment: Instead of `=1`, could you do `row()-4`? for the Time Slot.  Then kinda just do the same with `column()`?

Comment: Hmmmmm.  Let me try that.

Comment: That's genius.  If you put that as an answer I'll go ahead and upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to your second comment after my question, it looks like you just need to offset your `=1`.  A quick way (I'm sure there are many others) is to just do some basic arethmetic and use `row()` (which returns the row the cell is on) and then subtract `4`.  It's `4` because that's the row your headers are in:

`Row() - 4`

So, for columns, I'd think it's just `Column()-1`, since `A:A` has your "headers".

Edit: Ha! Taking another look, I think you could alternatively just reference the current row's `B` column: so instead of `row()-4`, try `$A5`.

Comment: Yep.  The method you talked about with using `ROW` and `COLUMN` works beautifully.  Thanks for this!!!